# Fade in a .addClass

Tags: jquery

I see this question has been asked before, but the function I have working is set up differently than the examples so I'm having trouble putting it all together.

I have a "hover" class that I'm adding to divs with class .steps that changes the background image. However I want it to fade in and out (like I'm doing on my other div with class .steps-hover.)

Here is what I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.steps').hover(over, out);
});

function over(event) {
  $('.steps').addClass("hover");
  $('.steps-hover', this).stop(true, true, true).fadeIn(500);
  $('.steps-hover', this).css("display", "normal");
}

function out(event) {
  $('.steps').removeClass("hover");
  $('.steps-hover', this).stop(true, true, true).fadeOut(500);
}
</script>
```

So how do I get the .addClass and .removeClass to fade in and out? I have a feeling this is pretty simple to do, but the things that I have tried have not worked and I am a jQuery beginner. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.steps').hover(over, out);
});

function over(event) {
  $(this).addClass("hover"); // the hover class has to be added to the specific `.steps` element which was hovered, not to all `.steps` elements
  $('.steps-hover', this).stop(true, true, true).fadeIn(500).css("display", "normal");
}

function out(event) {
  $(this).removeClass("hover"); //same as above
  $('.steps-hover', this).stop(true, true, true).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I didn't realize that was going to be a problem! Now is there a way to fade the class in and out?

Comment: @user2574250 slide in/out?

Comment: Just fade, like the .steps-hover is doing. I need them to sync together.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way? I have 3 buttons that I want to change the background image of on hover. Each image is different. I thought adding a class would be the way to go in order to keep them unique.